# Why does echo $-1 output this?

Tags: bash, shell

Can someone explain me what is happening here? What does the output means?

```
:$ echo $-3
himBH3
:$ echo $-2
himBH2
:$ echo $-1
himBH1
```

Thanks.

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164909/what-does-echo-1-display

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$-` is a [variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) that contains the currently active shell options.

> -
>
> (A hyphen.) Expands to the current option flags as specified upon invocation, by the set builtin command, or those set by the shell itself (such as the -i option).

Your command is evaluating to `the value of -` then a number.