# What does $- mean in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I was playing around on the shell when by mistake, I typed `echo $-` and I got the result `himBH`. Immediately, I tried all other combinations of symbols along with the $ sign but with no luck.
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26793022/why-does-echo-1-output-this) post but I didn't fully understand it. Can someone please epxlain what they mean by 'shell options' and what himBH is supposed to mean?

Much thanks!

Comment: More on options in shell... http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html

Comment: This is not really a dupe of the linked question. Other question already knows what is `$-` but asking specifically about what each character in `$-` is doing vs here the problem is the very meaning of `$-`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`$-` prints The current set of  options in your current shell.

`himBH` means following options are enabled:

- `H` - `histexpand`: when [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html#History-Interaction) is enabled
- `m` - `monitor`: when [job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html#Job-Control) is enabled
- `h` - `hashall`: Locate and remember (hash) commands as they are looked up for execution
- `B` - `braceexpand`: when [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) is enabled
- `i` - `interactive`: when current shell is interactive

Comment: Can I somehow check whether the current shell has X support, that is, whether it can open applications in windowed mode?

Comment: I found an answer to my latter question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11965765/1070480), but I'm still curious what the options in `$-` mean.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye: Checking X server running is not really related with `$-` options

Comment: Okay, but I'm still wondering what the options mean?

Comment: I have updated answer with more details.

Comment: Documented here as special parameter: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Shell never has X11 support. It just has an environment variable `$DISPLAY`. This is passed to child processes. If they have X11 support, then they use it to attach to the display.